# How to identify the message in a delivery notification?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

In pika, I have called `channel.confirm_delivery(on_confirm_delivery)` in order to be informed when messages are delivered successfully (or fail to be delivered). Then, I call `channel.basic_publish` to publish the messages. Everything is performed asynchronously.

How, when the `on_confirm_delivery` callback is called, do I find what the concerned message? In the parameters, The only information that changes in the object passed as a parameter to the callback is `delivery_tag`, which seems to be an auto-incremented number. However, `basic_publish` doesn't return any delivery tag.

In other words, if I call `basic_publish` twice, how do I know, when I receive an acknowledgement, whether it's the first or the second message which is acknowledged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From RabbitMQ document, I find:

> Delivery tags are monotonically growing positive integers and are presented as such by client libraries.

So you can keep a growing integer in your code per channel, set it to 0 when channel is open, increase it when you publish a message. Then this integer will be same as the `delivery_tag`.